# Fetch text from selected option and put it in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im using php to populate the Countries from database, and depends on what country is selected the Cities will show up in the second select box.

Now i Want the selected City show up in a textarea.
If user changes city again and then the textarea value need change to.

this is what i have.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="country_id" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('country'); ?></label>

      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select name="country_id" id = "country_id" class="select2" data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder="<?php echo get_phrase('select_country'); ?>" onchange="getCityList(this.value)">
          <option value="0"><?php echo get_phrase('none'); ?></option>
          <?php foreach ($countries as $country): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $country['id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="city_id"> <?php echo get_phrase('city'); ?></label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select class="form-control select2" name="city_id" id="city_id">
          <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_city'); ?></option>
        </select>
<textarea id="myPick"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried add this javascript but nothing happens.

```
<script>
$('select[name="city_id"]').change(function(){
    var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    if(text != ""){
       text = "Buy "+text;
    }

    $('#myPick').val(text);
});

</script>
```

Comment: 1. you can use `$('#city_id')` instead 2. how is the city select getting populated? 3. code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kq78w4nh/

Comment: city_id is also populated from database, depends on what county is pick and then city will show the correct cities.

The county and city are shown. the problem is just to fetch the city and put in the text area.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you. As you can see in my fiddle, your code works fine, provided there are options in the 2nd select. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: If i change the city_id name to country_id then the country name show up in the text area but not the city.

I checked the source code and I see all countries are loaded and shown in source code but not the cities, cities in only shown in the dropdown.

Comment: I assume you're populating the 2nd select using AJAX. Please add that code to the question so we can check it for problems, otherwise I have no choice but to recommend to close this question as "not reproducible".